# Is the execution of kernel code for handling a system call from a process considered part of the process?

Tags: linux, process, operating-system, computer-science, computer-science-theory

(I am mainly asking the following OS questions from computer science point of view. In the following, if I need to be specific about the OS, I am mainly talking about linux)

A process is defined as an execution of one or more programs.

Yet we often distinguish between user programs and an OS kernel (which also consists of programs).

- Does a process only execute user programs, not programs in an OS kernel?
- When a process issues a system call, the cpu then switches from user mode to kernel mode and executes the system call handler in the kernel code. Is the execution of the system call handler (as part of the kernel code) part of the process, or is it part of the execution of the OS kernel?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't normally say that the OS kernel consists of programs, especially not a monolithic kernel like Linux.

Comment: A kernel has subsystems which also have components. Do you consider a system call handler a program? Do you consider a page allocator in a virtual memory management a program? Do you consider a virtual file system a program?

Comment: No, different system call handlers are just different functions within the kernel.

Comment: do you mean a linux kernel is a single program, which can't be divided into programs? Unlike a process, a Linux kernel isn't an **execution** of a program, is it?

Comment: Yes. Microkernel OS (Minix, QNX, HURD) try to cleanly separate core functionality into separate, independent programs, but Linux is basically a large, single program. Most software has separate components and subsystems (e.g. logging, graphics renderer, physics engine, networking handler, etc), but you don't consider these pieces separate programs because they are all just linked into the same executable.

Comment: Of course it is - it's a call.

Answer (score 1):

In most operating systems, the "kernel" executes in the context of a process. There are some that work differently but this is the general mechanism use. A process switches between user mode and kernel mode (and some systems have additional modes).

> Does a process only execute user programs, not programs in an OS kernel?

There are no programs in an OS kernel (generally). A process can execute interrupt and exception handlers in kernel mode.

> When a process issues a system call, the cpu then switches from user mode to kernel mode and executes the system call handler in the kernel code. Is the execution of the system call handler (as part of the kernel code) part of the process, or is it part of the execution of the OS kernel?

The process. The same thing happens with interrupts.

Bill does an I/O request. Jim's process starts to run. Bill's I/O request completes and triggers and interrupt. Jim's process enter's kernel mode and handles Bill's I/O request.

Of course, system security prevents Jim's user mode code from having any access to Bill's data.